# Why does Selenium testing website not work on more than one page?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

The first part of the code work will work. But the second part doesn't work, and no error appears, and I don't know where the problem is. So please help.

**First part is the login page, and the second part is home page.**

```
package Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                        "E:\\Quality\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver =new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login");
        // first part//
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"session_key-login\"]")).click(); 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"session_keylogin\"]")).sendKeys("Email");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"session_password-login\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"session_password-login\"]")).sendKeys("*******");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btn-primary\"]")).click();
    // second part//
    WebElement test = null ;
    test.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[5]/aside/div/header")).click();

  }
}
```

Comment: try add some sleep after `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btn-primary\"]")).click();` to wait home page open completely

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck? What are you exactly trying to do in this step?

Comment: @DebanjanB last two lines

Answer (score 1):

You have putted a wrong id for `xpath` of email textbox.

You should use `session_key-login` instead of `session_keylogin`.

Just use the below revised code where you're using `sendKeys()` method:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"session_key-login\"]")).sendKeys("Email");
```

**2nd part Solution**

Skip WebElement declaration, thus comment the line  `//WebElement test = null;`

Use the line using `driver` object

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[5]/aside/div/header")).click();
```

You can also use xpath `//*[@id=\"msg-overlay\"]/div/header`
thus for the revised code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"msg-overlay\"]/div/header")).click();
```

Comment: actually the login part work will but the problem is in the last two line           WebElement test = null ;
    test.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[5]/aside/div/header")).click();

Comment: @Nourel-dineKhaled most probably you've made a mistake creating `WebElement` instance. so test object can't find the expected element. I have updated my answer. It is working fine at my end. Just try it and if it really helps you, please accept the answer and upvote it. Thanks.